Why is my project not being added to a folder within a Visual Studio 2022 solution with cmake?
I am trying to make a Visaul Studio 2022 solution, where "someexe" will be added to the folder "exefolder". However, someexe is not being added to exefolder. I have attempted to set the folder property in both the solution (I am running cmake on the "scripts\x64\CMakeLists.txt" example below), and in the project "someexe"
My folder structure is
root
    |--someexe
       |--CMakeLists.txt
    |--scripts
       |--x64
          |--CMakeLists

someexe\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(someexe)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ../main.cpp)

set_target_properties(someexe PROPERTIES FOLDER "exefolder")

scripts\x64\CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(x64-Platform)
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)
add_subdirectory(../../someexe x64_someexe)

set_target_properties(someexe PROPERTIES FOLDER "exefolder")


The issue was that scripts\x64\CMakeLists.txt was set to VERSION 3.10, where this was not available yet in this capacity.

To enable organizing code into folders, you need to set the global USE_FOLDERS property to ON.

I have attempted to set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON) to both CMakeLists.txt, under project and there still is not a folder being shown

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
